# Angular 6 Promise is calling a function twice

Tags: angular6

I'm new to Angular and I'm currently facing an issue with Promises. The function getContents() is called twice when showMoreClickedHandler() is called. On other occasions, getContents() is called only once. I checked the breakpoints and looks like it goes back to line no 1 when const reqGetContentsPromise is undefined. Below is the code. Any help will be much appreciated!

```
getContents(): Promise<Content[]> {
    console.log('Contents called twice');
    this.getContentsCalled = true;
    this.spinner.show();



    const reqGetContentsPromise = this.salesforceService.getContents(
        this.pageNum,
        this.resultsPerPage,
        this.sortBy,
        this.sortDir,
        this.filterType,
        this.filterVal,
        this.searchVal,
        this.courseId
    );

    reqGetContentsPromise.then(
        resData => {
            this.contents = this.contents.concat(resData);
        },
        err => {
            this.contents = [];
        }
    );

    return reqGetContentsPromise;
}
```

showMoreClickedHandler(): void {

```
    console.log('Show more called');

    this.pageNum++;
    this.getContents();
    $('#search-content-div').animate({ scrollTop: $('#search-content-div').prop('scrollHeight') }, 500);
}
```